# how to break on error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

Is there a simple way to set a breakpoint one line before an error in the native browser debuggers such as Chrome and Safari? If not, what tools are there that will accomplish this task?

Comment: How can it break BEFORE the error? How does it know there will be an error until it gets to that line.

Comment: Put `debugger` in your code at the point you want the browser to halt at the breakpoint inside the dev tool.

Comment: I'm asking if there is some sort of lookahead function that will find an error, roll back and then put the breakpoint one line before the error so that you can explore the program state. As it is, I have to look at the error logs, set a break point, then run through the code. If the line is in a function called multiple times, I have to count the executions and then run the code twice. Its annoying. I think the "pause on caught exceptions" option in chrome is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open developer tools in Chrome and go to Sources tab. At the right hand side where you'll find the controls to step through your code you can click on the pause button once and it will turn blue. Now when an error happens it will pause your code at that line.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this with your console open:

```js
var a = 0
debugger; //console will stop and start debug mode at this breakpoint.
var b = a.test.test2; //this will fail
```